# How to change a View's height in ListView and don't make its child re-layout?

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

I need to implement this things, a height of item in ListView will be reduced slowly, when its height reduce to 0, it's gone. On this process, the remain views that below the item, should move up slowly.

At First, I use the ObjectAnimator to change the 'scaleY', but the size of item occupy was not changed, when Animator ends, ListView refresh, the empty rectangle was gone.

```
ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(itemView, 'scaleY', 1f, 0f);
```

And I found another way to do this, I write a Runnable to change the height of the item, but there are some child view in my item, like a ImageView, with the height changing, the ImageView changing too, I think this is not look well.

```
LayoutParams lp = itemView.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = newHeight;
itemView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

At last, I found third way to do, change the 'bottom' value of the item, yes, It looks like a window with reducing height, but height not changed, the remain views that below the item didn't move until Runnable ends and ListView refresh.

```
itemView.setBottom(itemView.getTop() + newHeight);
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar to this and work fine:

```
public  void collapse(final View v, final int toHeight, final int toWidth) {
        final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

        Animation a = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {


                v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (toHeight * interpolatedTime);


                v.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (toWidth * interpolatedTime);

                v.requestLayout();


            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // 1dp/ms
        a.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        a.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        v.startAnimation(a);

    }
```

the height set in the layout can not be fixed (put wrap_content). Hope it help you!!

Comment: This is also like my second way. the only one side effect: children of item will also be changed.

Comment: You change the height to the itemView. You should change only the elements that you want change. You can do this in your custom Adapter, when you get all the views of the itemView.